# Как сделать так, чтобы в woocommerce показывало, какая категория выбрана?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Вставил с помощью шорт кода на страницу магазина категории. По шаблону нужно сделать так, чтобы при переходе на категорию - показывало, какая выбрана. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?
Как вставлен шорт код:

```
<div class="categories">
                    <div class="row">
                        <a href="#" class="tab">
                        <?php echo do_shortcode( '[product_categories hide_empty=0]' ); ?>
                        </a>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать без шорткода

```
<div class="categories">
                    <div class="row">
                        <a href="#" class="tab">
                        
                               <?php $active_category = get_queried_object(); ?>  
                        
                               <?php 
                                    $args = array(
                                                                  'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
                                                                  'orderby'      => 'name',
                                                                  'hide_empty'   => 0
                                    );

                                    $terms = get_categories( $args );
                                    
                                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                        
                                            $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
                                            
                                            $active = ($active_category -> term_id == $term -> term_id) ? 'class="active"' : '';
                                            
                                            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '" '.$active.'>' . $term -> name . '</a>';
                                    }
                               ?>
                        </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо!) А можете подсказать, как добавить к каждому элементу статичный класс? С таким не сталкивался просто никогда

Comment: @Dikkkey к ссылке добавить класс? просто атрибут к <a> пропишите

Comment: Оно просто как-то не так работает. Вложил этот php код в тег "a", но оно просто списком в .row идет да и всё